# Is it possible to customize character's vertical offset with CSS?

Tags: css

So I would like a certain span to have ALL it's letters centered, no matter the character. So a period `.` would look like `·` and a underscore `_` would look like `-`.

Is it possible to center EVERY character to the middle using just CSS instead of making a custom font?

I've tried messing with span's height, character's line height and baseline. Nothing seems to work. It seems that every character has an offset set to it, and I'm hoping to be able to override it.

Comment: Have you tried with `line-height`?

Comment: @AshokShah, yes. I mentioned that already. Basically the character now *overflows* from the line instead of fitting in the line.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what outcome you want because an underline in many fonts will naturally be below a full stop for example. I can see how to push all the characters in a span up by the same amount but I don't see how a full stop and an underline could end up at the same vertical level without a redesigned font.